# Comparación de cadenas no exactas en Django

Tags: python, django

Estoy intentando hacer una comparación de cadenas, de campos extraidos de una web mediante webscrapping, con el campo 'nombre' de una tabla en Base de Datos en django.

Si yo tengo por un lado 'Producto 54 Naranja Sesion' y por otro lado 'Sesion Producto 54 Nr' como puedo hacer para que encuentre resultados.

Con name__contains no me funciona la mayoría de los casos, me serviría solo en el caso de que la cadena fuera 'Producto 54', ya que sería como un LIKE en SQL.

```
 Products.objects.filter(name__contains=data['search'])
```

Después, hay una librería Difflib que compara cadenas, pero lo único que me devuelve es el ratio de coincidencia, lo que no me sirve para nada.

Comment: ¿Cual es el patrón de búsqueda especifico, que quieres aplicar? `%text%` o  `%text`, etc??

Comment: Te diría que un %text% pero no me ha funcionado. Ni cogiendo una parte que puede estar en las dos cadenas, ya que hay productos que el nombre tiene poca coincidencia.

Comment: Te sugiero revisar la [documentación de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#contains) sobre `contains`, es equivalente a: `SELECT ... LIKE '%text%';`, por lo cual te debería funcionar sin ningún problema. Estas seguro que `data['search']` contiene el valor que estas esperando?. Por otra parte, ten en cuenta que `contains` es sensible a minúsculas y mayúsculas (a menos que utilices SQLite como gestor de base de datos, ya que no lo soporta), por lo cual no puede tener las coincidencias que deseas.

Comment: O puedes intentar utilizar [`icontains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#icontains) que es insensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas, ya que cabe la posibilidad de que pueda ser ese problema.